# How gxip -c works

Tags: linux, bash, compression, gzip

I'm trying to understand how the gzip's "-c" option works.

```
gzip -c
```

Usage example:

```
gzip -c ${micro} >> ${macro}.gz
```

So this will concatenate micro into macro.gz, but whats the workflow?
will it first temporarely gunzip macro.gz, append micro, and then gzip again?
Its important for me to understand this, i have to do some jobs where i dont have a lot of eden space available and therefore all has to be gzipped and never decompressed.

Thx

Comment: ` ... therefore all has to be gzipped and never decompressed.` -- Chances are that you don't need the `-c` option.  `-c` writes the output to `STDOUT` so that you can redirect it to a file.

Comment: hi @devnull thx, and in the case of 'simple' append redirection >> will this mean that the text is appended directly whithout the decompression of the gzip file?

Answer (score 1):

First, if the data will never be decompressed, then you can send it to `/dev/null` instead.

To answer your question, no, it will not gunzip macro.gz.  It will simply append a gzip stream to macro.gz.  Per the standard, a concatenation of gzip streams is a valid gzip stream, so gunzipping that concatenation will give you the concatenation of the uncompressed inputs.  That is, if in fact you do want to decompress it someday.